# Auto generate name based on user input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two Input fields I want to name based on user input but this name should be lowercase and spaces between words change to "-". I am doing like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#name").keyup(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var alias = name.charAt(0);
    $("#alias").val(alias);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="name" class="text-input medium-input" type="text" id="name" value="" />

<input name="alias" class="text-input medium-input" type="text" id="alias" />
```

This given me result **I write "arslan" in first input field then showing "a" in second input field**
Showing only one letter

Comment: You are using `.charAt(0)` thus getting first character. Can you share few inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: I want like this "Home services" then second input field make "home-services"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to name based on user input but this name should be lowercase
>   and spaces between words change to "-".

Use `replace`

```
$("#alias").val( name.replace( /\s+/g, "-" ) );
```

Your function should look like

```
 $(function() {
     $("#name").keyup(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        $("#alias").val( name.toLowerCase().replace( /\s+/g, "-" ) );
     });
  });
```

Comment: And for conversion to lowercase, use : `name.toLowerCase()`

Comment: @ekqnp Thanks, I missed the same.

Comment: I think he wants .toLowerCase() as well.

Comment: @ekqnp, you got to it before my slow browser could submit, haha.

Comment: @adpro Happens to me all the time :)

Comment: Thanks buddy Its very helpful for me. I want exactly this

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the whole entry from name input to alias while replacing the spaces with '-' and turning it to lower case.

```
$("#name").keyup(function() {
  $("#alias").val($(this).val().replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

```
var name = $("#name").val().toLowerCase();
var alias = name.split(" ").join("-");
$("#alias").val(alias);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
 $(function() {
      $("#name").keyup(function() {
       var name = $("#name").val().toLowerCase();
       $("#alias").val(name.replace(/-/g,' '));
     });
  });
```

The `replace` will change all `-` given in the name with space